# NativeScript RadListView: Infinite scroll to top?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

I'm using the latest nativescript (3.1.1) and RadListView. I'm trying to achieve infinite scrolling when the user scrolls up the list (similar to how Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp and other chat apps work).

I know `loadOnDemand` works great but it works only when the user scrolls down. Is there a way to make `loadOnDemand` work when the user scrolls up? Or any other workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: Non of the apps you pointed out have infinite up scrolling, for example the "Whatsapp" simply start at the bottom of a chat and if that chat is long it may look/feel like it is infinite but if you scroll enough you will end up at the top of the "listview". I am not aware of any app's that have an "load on demand" when scrolling upwards, for that direction all apps you "pull to refresh" which is supported in the RadListView component.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov in whatsapp, look at the scroller on the right when you scroll up, you will see it getting smaller while you're scrolling upwards - that's what I call infinite scrolling upwards

Comment: In the RadListView in Android in {N} showing the vertical/horizontal scrollbar is not possible due to limitations that come from the Android framework + the NativeScript  in showing those scrollbars. In Android showing those scrollbars is done only via the XML which in the NativeScript framework is not accessible and all "native" operations need to be done via code. Due to this limitation of only using the XML we cannot provide any customizations of showing/hiding that scrollbar.

Comment: I'm not looking to show the scrollbar, it was just an example. All I need is the same requirement as any chat client has - the latest messages are shown at the bottom, and if you scroll up you get the next page of old messages once you hit the top (or close to the top).

Answer (score 1):

The current version of RadListView does not provide such "load on demand in upwards direction" feature, it does provide "pull to refresh" and "load on demand from bottom".

You can achieve this with some custom implementation using the **scrolling events** of the `RadListView` as explained in the *discourse.nativescript.org* thread [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-radlistview-infinite-scroll-to-top/2177/6). I will post the answer's text here also for better visibility to the community:

> Actually I think you might easily achieve this using the scrolling
>   events exposed by RadListView:
>   http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/scrolling
>
> You can use the scrolled in particular:
>   http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#scrolledevent
>
> This event exposes the current scroll offset of the list. Once it
>   becomes 0 or negative you can start a data-fetch process, raise a flag
>   that a process is undergoing and reset it once the data has arrived.

Comment: I know this thread is old but I'm trying to implement a similar feature and already tried what is described in the quote from discord and it is working but the issue is I'm using unshift to add item to the beginning of the array and the list moves to the top when new items are added. I want it to stay at it's original position so the user can scroll up rather then being lost in a jumping list. Any idea how I can persist list position? I tried scrollToIndex but it scrolls so the item is in the viewport at the bottom of the list - I need it to be in the same place where it was before initially.